# MVC menu not working after Areas is added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have this menu that's point to:

```
new { Controller = "Administration", Action = "RolesUsers" }
```

It's working fine before I discover Areas in MVC today.

After I added a new area "Administration", menu above is not working anymore even if I tell it to point to root by using `Area = ""`:

```
new { Area = "", Controller = "Administration", Action = "RolesUsers" }
```

It said:

> The resource cannot be found. 
>     Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Administration/RolesUsers

```
new { Area = "Administration", Controller = "Role", Action = "Index" }
```

Is it possible for me to fix this without moving `RolesUsers` into the new `Administration` area?

Here is my "root" route config:

```
namespace ControlTower2Report
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultWithCulture",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") },
                namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default", // Route name
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                //defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Pages", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "DashboardOwn", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "overPurchase", // Route name
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{forecastYear}/{purchaseStatus}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Pages", action = "FilterByStatus", forecastYear = UrlParameter.Optional, purchaseStatus = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Area route config?:

```
namespace ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration
{
    public class AdministrationAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Administration";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Administration_default",
                "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { culture = "en", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "Administration_defaultWithCulture",
                "{culture}/Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") },
                namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
          );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you still have a controller called Administration?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Yes. But other menus are not working too and those are not belong to AdministrationController.

Comment: did you add a namespace with your routing registrations.. if not do this! then ensure that all action links include the area.

Comment: @Seabizkit but how? New to MVC.

Comment: see example here: https://forums.asp.net/t/1840032.aspx?Trying+to+specify+a+namespace+to+a+route+but+getting+error     make sure your main route and the area route have different namespaces. just follow the namespace of where they located.

Comment: @Seabizkit still not working, I register them wrongly?

Comment: yes it appears you are register them wrongly.  you have your main `RouteConfig.cs` and then `YouAreaHereAreaRegistration.cs` these should be different. ie. in mine they are `namespaces: new[] { "Paradox.Web.Controllers" } //need for when using areas` and `namespaces: new[] { "Paradox.Web.Areas.Importer.Controllers" } //need for when using areas`

Comment: mmm i take it back maybe you are registering correctly... now what seems to be the problem. PS Remember that the Controllers must have the same namespace as the registered Route! ie all your Administator controllers must have the namespace you regerested they would be in aka `ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration.Controllers` if you moving stuff around you may forget to realign the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving 'culture' in routing:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
        context.MapRoute(
            "Administration_default",
            "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Administration_defaultWithCulture",
            "{culture}/Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { culture = "en", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") },
            namespaces: new string[] { "ControlTower2Report.Areas.Administration.Controllers" }
      );
}
```